# Mat-checkbox within a mat-expansion-panel shifts vertically on check

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a `mat-checkbox` inside of a `mat-expansion-panel` as a "Select All" checkbox in an accordion. When I check or uncheck this box, it shifts vertically a few pixels to the point where it is half hidden behind the panel above it. Has anyone else experienced this and is there a fix?

```html
    <mat-accordion multi>
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" (change)="selectBenefitsGroup(benefitGroup)"
          [(ngModel)]="benefitGroup.checked" class="select-all">
            {{benefitGroup.viewValue}}
          </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before and use the following workaround. It may not be the best way but seems to get the job done.

Add the following to top level style:

```
.checkbox-header .mat-content {
  height: 24px;
}
```

And then add `.checkbox-header` class to `mat-expansion-panel-header` with checkboxes

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-he4r4i?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give this a shot

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks so much for the help